# Combining multiple excel files by the name of their sheets using rstudio

Tags: r, dplyr, export-to-excel

In my folder I do have 45 different excel files, each having only one sheet and different data structure. I want to import them in R and then just export them back into one single excel file. Till here I can do with the help of google. However I want the sheet names of the individual sheets in the exported file to be what they were in the original file. Below is what my code looks like till now and I can't seem to figure out how to change it (this code works fine just not the way I want).

```r
setwd("C:\\Users\\I0510906\\OneDrive - Sanofi\\Desktop\\Insulin\\IQVIA Files\\RAuto\\PERFB\\INSULIN\\")
data.files <- list.files(pattern = "*.xlsx")

# read the files
files <- lapply(data.files, function(x) read.xlsx2(x, sheetIndex = 1))


for (i in 1:length(data.files)){    
  # loading the workbook or excel file
  wbook <- loadWorkbook(data.files[i])   
  
  #extracting sheets from the individual workbooks
  sheet <- getSheets(wbook)                      
  
  for (j in 1:length(sheet)){ 
        assign(paste("global.", i,j, sep = ""), 
           read.xlsx2(data.files[i], sheetIndex=j, 
                      as.data.frame=TRUE, header=TRUE))
    
  }
}


for (i in 1:length(data.files)) {
  if(i==1)
    write.xlsx(files[[i]], file="global-data.xlsx", 
               sheetName = paste("global",i))
  else 
    write.xlsx(files[[i]], file="global-data.xlsx", 
               sheetName = paste("global",i), append=TRUE)
}
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Currently it is setting the name of sheets in the exported final file to be Global1/2/3 etc. while what I want is the sheet names should be XYZ/ABC/DEF etc. which were exactly at the time of importing them in RStudio.

## EDIT

To make it more clear, I have a folder with 45 files inside. All of them have different structure. My need is not to create a single DF.

e.g. my first excel file is named "SLIDE1". The sheet name is also "SHEET1". Same way the 45th file will have a sheet named "SLIDE45".

After importing all the 45 of them, I want to export them back as one single excel file with 45 different worksheets and name of each of the worksheet would be "SLIDE1/SLIDE2/....../SLIDE45" and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
library(tidyverse)
files <- list.files("C:\\Users\\I0510906\\OneDrive - Sanofi\\Desktop\\Insulin\\IQVIA Files\\RAuto\\PERFB\\INSULIN\\",
                    pattern = ".xlsx$",
                    full.names = TRUE)

files_list <- map(files, rio::import) |> 
  setNames(tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(files)))

rio::export(files_list, "C:\\Users\\I0510906\\OneDrive - Sanofi\\Desktop\\Insulin\\IQVIA Files\\RAuto\\PERFB\\INSULIN\\insulin.xlsx")
```

- `map` iterates over the vector files and applies the same function to each file (in this case `import`) and returns a list with one element per iteration (essentially The same as `lapply`)
- `rio::import` can handle most file types automatically and is easier to use than `loadWorkbook`
- `setNames` sets names to each list elements
- `rio::export` likewise can handle most file types and uses sensible default values for export. When given a named list of data.frames, it writes each element into a sheet

Comment: Hi JBGruger, no , I don't want to make a single DF out of all the 45 files I do have. Instead after importing 45 individual files from the folder, I want to export them back to the same folder however all the 45 worksheets in a single file. My code above is doing that fine however when renaming the sheets in the exported file it is renaming them as "global1","global2" etc. Instead what I want is these sheets to be named as the original sheet name they got imported as. I feel it would need creating a list of Sheet names from 45 files and then loop through it while exporting. I am unsure how to?

Comment: Ok, got it. Should work now

Comment: This works like a charm JBGruger. Big thank, you saved me a lot of time and something new to learn instead of writing bulky for loop :)